# Which object pool backing store to choose?

Tags: c#, memory-management, .net-4.0, object-pooling, memory-pool

In our C# (.NET 4.0) application, we allocate and de-allocate **a lot** of memory, in different size chunks. We want to move to an object pool, to improve performance.

We implemented an object pool already and saw some performance improvement. We're currently using a stack-based backing store. Other possible alternatives are, queue based store, ConcurrentBag<> based store, List<> based store, etc.

I guess the choice of backing store really depends on the application's characteristics, so we're now in the process of implementing the object pool with all these different backing stores and testing the performance.

However, I'd really like to hear your thoughts on pros and cons of different backing stores for object pooling.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No answers to this question so far, so I'll write my own answer:

Ended up using a Stack<>. Credit to : http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2008/08/07/speedy-c-part-2-optimizing-memory-allocations---pooling-and.aspx

We just experimented with different backing stores and Stack<> turned out to be the fastest in our particular case.

Comment: You never stated what kind of objects you're pooling. Reference types or value types? That makes a huge difference

Comment: @MattDavey: They were variable sized byte arrays.

Comment: I don't think it is so much what you are pooling (well -- past value vs. reference types), rather than the access patterns.  That implementation of a Object Pool is going to be absolutely terrible in highly concurrent code since it locks on the get/return methods.